# SQL para verificar número saltado

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Possuo uma tabela com 12.560 registros de 5 anos atrás, ou seja, não tem uma modelagem tão boa assim e possui um campo chamado 'código' que o usuário preenchia com algo como CA-0001. O problema é que em algum momento na história desse banco de dados alguém pulou um número e preciso saber que número foi esse. Qual a query que eu executaria para descobrir qual linha foi saltada?

OBS.: Estou usando SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Use uma sql do tipo select * from tabela t1 where seq > 1 and not exists (select null from tabela t2 where t2.seq = (t1.seq-1))

Comment: O problema é que o campo está em varchar

Comment: Use functions como SUBSTRING  para obter a parte numérica e CAST ou CONVERT para converter a string para numero , CONCAT para recompor a nova string

Comment: Transforma em uma resposta

Comment: @MárcioEric: Pesquise por algoritmos de _gaps and islands_.

Comment: Não rapaz, para que eu possa marcar como solução. Era no registro 133

Comment: O @Sorack o fez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode remover as letras do código e depois compara-lo com a mesma tabela usando `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT codigo
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT
                    FROM tabela t2
                   WHERE CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(t1.codigo, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t1.codigo), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(t1.codigo, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t1.codigo), 8000) + 'X') -1) AS INT) - 1
                       = CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(t2.codigo, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t2.codigo), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(t2.codigo, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', t2.codigo), 8000) + 'X') -1) AS INT) - 1)
```

A solução acima mostrará o registro que não possui antecessor.

Referência da remoção de caracteres não numéricos: [T-SQL select query to remove non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18625635/3388148)